# Grails: What is the best way to access domain classes from a src/groovy class?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

The Grails [FAQ](http://grails.org/FAQ#Q:%20How%20can%20I%20access%20domain%20classes%20from%20sources%20in%20src/groovy?) says this:

> Q: How can I access domain classes from sources in src/groovy?
>
> Sometimes, you are developing some utility classes that live in src/groovy and which you intend >to use from Services and other artifacts. However, as those classes are pre-compiled by Grails, >it is not possible to instantiate them and write things like Book.findByTitle("Groovy in >Action"). But fortunately, there is a workaround since it's possible to do this:
>
> import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
>
> //…
>
> def book = ApplicationHolder.application.getClassForName("library.Book").findByTitle("Groovy in Action")
>
> The application MUST have finished bootstrapping before the dynamic Gorm methods will function correctly.

However, it appears that I can directly import domain objects and use GORM methods in my src/groovy classes without any problem, e.g.:

```
Book.findByTitle("Groovy in Action")
```

Since ApplicationHolder is deprecated, this advice must be out of date, but is there still any reason to avoid using domain classes directly from src/groovy?

Comment: Older versions of grails implemented auto-reloading of modified artefacts in dev mode by using different class loaders for artefact (grails-app) and non-artefact (src/groovy) classes. More recent grails versions use an agent-based reloading approach instead, and it's all in the one class loader.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, you referring to an out dated information. You can use domain classes inside classes defined under `src/groovy`.

The only overhead is that you have to handle `transactions` manually. On the contrary, `services` inside `grails-app/services` handes transaction by default. Services take care of transactions when the `transactional` flag is set to true (default is true of nothing specified).

On the other hand, when you access domain classes from `src/groovy` you have to use `withTransaction` block to handle transactions manually..

```
Book.withTransaction{status->
    def book = Book.findByTitle("Groovy in Action")
    book.title = "Grails in Action"
    book.save()

    status.setRollbackOnly() //Rolls back the transaction
}
```

Refer [withTransaction](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html) for details.

Comment: Works for Grails 3.3.5